# Laravel setting vhosts on XAMPP for pretty urls (routing issue)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use XAMPP localhost server and I recently got into possession of a introductory book regarding Laravel. I'd like to configure it propery but I stumbled upon a rock.

I don't know much about routing, but I enabled mod_rewrite, and included `opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` using the setting that Dayle Rees recommends, that is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_project
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/public
    CustomLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/app/storage/logs/access.log common
    ErrorLog /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/app/storage/logs/error.log
    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/public>
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options -MultiViews
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot opt/lampp/htdocs/choqlet/
    ServerName choqlet
    ServerAlias localhost/choqlet
</VirtualHost>
```

After i've done this, due to the rerouting, I do have an access to the laravel files, but when I want to access my other projects on the localhost, I constantly get redirected to the Laravel's index. Here's the `.htaccess` file contents from laravel's public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

     Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

     Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I guess that I'm doing something totally wrong here or Rewrite rules are just screwed?